# How set variable in Alamofire and get to another function

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJson

public class MyExample{

var myarray=[String]()

func onCreate(){
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://myurl.org/get", ).responseJSON { response in
            let json = JSON(value)
            let list: Array<JSON> = json.arrayValue
for element in list{
  myarray.append(element["name"].stringValue)
         }

}
func getMyArray(){return myarray}
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Show what you've tried and where you are experiencing problems.

Comment: yes.I want set arguments in array with alamofire but when try to get the array returns nil

Answer (score 0):

OK I had the same problem but in objective C.

The problem is your array is fill after the return. If you ant to see why use debug.

The solution is use semaphore.

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJson

public class MyExample{

var myarray=[String]()
//create a semaphore and init it
func onCreate(){
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://myurl.org/get", ).responseJSON { response in
            let json = JSON(value)
            let list: Array<JSON> = json.arrayValue
for element in list{
  myarray.append(element["name"].stringValue)
// use the semaphore
 }

    }
//use function to wait until the semaphore is done by the other thread.
    func getMyArray(){return myarray}
    }
```

You can find many information about semaphore on google.
If it help you **vote for me**.